# Change ANT's JDK in Netbeans 6.9

Tags: netbeans, ant, netbeans-6.9

Hope I can get a bit of help here.

I am compiling some legacy code that was written for java 1.5.  It builds fine with Netbeans own ant build file, but not with the legacy build file.
When I run the legacy Ant file it returns the following error:

```
is not abstract and does not override abstract method setNClob(int,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.PreparedStatement
```

And this requires Java 1.5 to compile.  I have already set source="1.5" target="1.5" in the javac tag in the ant script.
I assume I need to run Ant in Netbeans to run under java 1.5.

So how do I set the Ant to point to a different JDK when running in Netbeans 6.9?

Answer (score 0):

When I use netbeans, I usually don't try to edit the netbeans generated build files.  Rather, if you haven't already:

o Bring up the project in netbeans

o right-click on the project and choose "Properties".

o In properties, choose "Libraries" and you should see a selection for Java platform.

o Try changing via drop-down, or if 1.5 is not available there, click "Manage Platforms"

Netbeans should make the necessary changes to your build file and you should then be able to build from the command prompt.

Comment: Yes indeed it will build using NetBeans own build file, but I'm trying to run an existing legacy build file.  Which begs the question how does netbeans use the platform to kick of the ant build and how can I use that in a standalone ant build file.

Comment: that would have been a good way to originally state the question.

Comment: fair point, I have added some more detail.  Sometimes it's easy to assume things.